# Not able execute netsh interface command in python

Tags: python, netsh

I am not able  execute "netsh interface tcp set global nonsackrttresiliency=enabled" command even as admin in python.could any body please help

Comment: Please include what errors you are getting in your question as well.

Comment: I am executing this in admin prompt

import os
os.system('netsh interface tcp set global nonsackrttresiliency=enabled')

getting error as "Set global command failed on IPv4 The parameter is incorrect."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  run `os.system('netsh interface tcp set global nonsackrttresiliency=enabled')` first with my 32 bit python then with my 64 bit python.

For the 32-bit python, I got the same error as you ie "Set global command failed on IPv4 The parameter is incorrect."

For the 64-bit python, everything just run smoothly and I had an 'Ok."

It turns out that the 32-bit python is running the process in WOW64 mode which makes your architecture appear as "x86". There may be a fix for that which I don't know yet but for now, what seems to work is to run the command in a 64-bit python interpreter.

**UPDATE:** I found something helpful over [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2012-March/012121.html). It's possible to still run it with your 32-bit python but as the link described, you'll need to disable the redirection to SysWOW64. Here's the final code which you can run from an administrator command prompt.

```
import ctypes
import os
k32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
wow64 = ctypes.c_long( 0 )
k32.Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection( ctypes.byref(wow64) )
os.system('netsh interface tcp set global nonsackrttresiliency=enabled')
k32.Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection( wow64 )
```

Comment: thanks for the help.But I can not change python to 64 bit in my user machines.Is there any workaround for this

Comment: You have to download and install a 64-bit version of python. Afterwards, you can get the 64-bit python interpreter by running python in your command prompt from the 64-bit python directory.

Comment: Have you been able to install the 64-bit version of python?

Comment: Yes I am able to install.But the problem is there  are lot many users which were using this script with python 32.So I can not  ask all of them port to 64 bit

Comment: Yeah, that's very true. I have updated my answer for those who still want to stick to the 32-bit python.